# What circuit element is this? Rectangle with diagonal arrow, called G

Tags: diagram

What kind of circuit elements are  \$G_\mathrm{Na}\$ and \$G_\mathrm{K}\$ in this circuit diagram? 
[image: Circuit Diagram]
I understand that \$G_\mathrm{L}\$ is a conductance, but what about the arrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are variable conductances, think of them as potentiometers with the slider connected to one end. The currents Ina, Ik and Il depend on the values of the conductances and the voltages.

Comment: Aha. Does it mean anything that the arrow goes into the actual wire symbol? I've only seen variable resistances with a disconnected arrow across before.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, there are several symbols for pots. That is a common way of depicting a variable resistance.